# How to patch jest-rutime when using Yarn 2?

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I am trying to follow the instructions in this repository to patch Jest.

[Patch Jest](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/next-page-tester/#optional-patch-jest).

It is suggested to use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) but I figured out that I can use [yarn patch](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch) when using Yarn 2.

I managed to patch jest-runtime but seems Jest doesn’t seem to require `jest-runtime` in its package so I don’t know where it comes from to use it as a reference to declare the patched file.

[Jest package.json](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/package.json)

I understand if Jest was the one that needs to be patched I could declare it like this:

`package.json`

```json
"devDependencies": {
   "jest": "patch:jest@26.6.3#./patches/jest.patch"
}
```

I tried to use the same logic to include the following code to include `jest-runtime` but it didn't work.

```json
"devDependencies": {
   "jest": "^26.6.3",
   "jest-runtime": "patch:jest-runtime@26.6.3#./patches/jest-runtime.patch"
}
```

How can I declare this patched jest-runtime so Jest can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions) field in the manifest is the correct approach to declare the patched modules that we didn't add to `devDependencies` such as submodules.

The `resolutions` field allows you to instruct Yarn to use a specific resolution instead of anything the resolver would normally pick. This is useful to enforce all your packages to use a single version of a dependency, or backport a fix.

The fix for that issue:

```json
{
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jest-runtime": "patch:jest-runtime@26.6.3#./patches/jest-runtime.patch"
  },
}
```